# Why is my browsing history visible outside my network?

Tags: web-browser, privacy, data-leakage, chrome

Whatever I and my family members do at 'Home PC' is visible in the history in Google chrome in my 'Office PC'. The two networks are entirely different!

I saw all websites visited on our home PC by my brother on my office PC. I notice it is mostly Facebook and GMail and Google search results.

I do acknowledge that I open my same GMail account in office and home.

What is happening? I suspect that Google is porting our web activities by associating it with my email ID which I open at home and office. But I am not that aware in security.

Answer (score 8):

Google Chrome has a Sync feature that synchronizes browsing history, configurations, bookmarks, etc. between Chrome browsers using the same [Google Account](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Account). You've very likely used your Google/GMail account when starting Google Chrome the first time on both computers.

You can [change the sync settings](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1281195?hl=en) on your home computer and disable the items you don't want to sync. For example, you can disable syncing the browsing history.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably Signed-in to the Chrome web browser. In case you did, Chrome does sync history, tabs, extensions and other stuff, which might be the reason why you are experiencing this?